# NOT IN , MATCHES in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

i have a two relations in pig:

### A,B

```
DUMP A;
```

> Sandeep Rohan Mohan

```
DUMP B;
```

> MOHAN

i need to get output as A - B;
Relation C should give me

> Sandeep,Rohan

since they not present in B

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
A1 = LOAD 'Sandeep Rohan Mohan' USING PigStorage() AS (line:chararray);
B1 = LOAD 'MOHAN' USING PigStorage() AS (line:chararray);

A = FOREACH A1 GENERATE UPPER(line) AS line;
B = FOREACH B1 GENERATE UPPER(line) AS line;

C = COGROUP A BY line, B BY line;

D = FILTER C BY IsEmpty(B);

E = FOREACH D GENERATE group AS name;

DUMP E;
```

> (ROHAN) (SANDEEP)

also refer [sets operations in apache pig](http://agiletesting.blogspot.in/2012/02/set-operations-in-apache-pig.html)

Answer (score 0):

achieved it with a left outer join, considered only those tuples which had nulls in $1